# Webpack node sass error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I have the following:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');  
const injectConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({  
  template: './index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {  
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [injectConfig]
}
```

and when I run "npm run start" as per my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-chart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Alessandro Santese",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-easy-chart": "^0.3.0",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had this error a while ago try the below to things - worked for me:

1. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` in your project and try to re-run your webpack build afterwards
2. If that doesn't help delete your project's `node_modules` directory in the project and webpack rebuild

I think the first one should already fix your issue, but if not the second one should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried them both but I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

This helped:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 6.0.0
```